# Does Anyone Know Anything about the Determinant and/or Inverse of this Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix I am inquiring about here is the $n \times n$ matrix where the entry $A_{ij}$ is $\frac{1}{(i+j-1)^2}$. The $2 \times 2$ matrix looks like 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/4 \\
1/4 & 1/9
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The $3 \times 3$ case looks like 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/4 & 1/9 \\
1/4 & 1/9 & 1/16 \\
1/9 & 1/16 & 1/25 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The $n \times n$ matrix looks like
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/4 & \cdots & 1/(n^2) \\
1/4 & 1/9 & \cdots & 1/{(n+1)^2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
1/(n^2) & 1/{(n+1)^2} & \cdots & 1/{(2n-1)^2}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
If anyone has any information or knows of any papers talking about this matrix please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I think this could stand some motivation.

Comment: It's the Hadamard product of the Hilbert matrix with itself, so it is positive definite and its determinant is positive.

Comment: You can give a formula for the determinant using the Jacobi-Trudi identities

Comment: When $n=5$, the numerator of the determinant is divisible by the large prime $179357$.  This implies that, unlike the Hilbert matrix, there is no simple formula for the determinant as a ratio of products of factorials.

Answer (score 14):

Not an answer, but an amusing observation: The determinant of the matrix usually (but not always) has denominator a perfect square (empirically), while the numerator always seems to have a huge prime factor.

**EDIT** Actually, it seems that the expectation of $\log(P(n))/\log(n),$ where $P(n)$ is the largest prime factor of $n$ approaches the [Golomb-Dickman constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb%E2%80%93Dickman_constant), which is about 0.62. In view of this, the largest prime factor of the numerator is pretty much par for the course, or at least, not obviously NOT par for the course.

n=1: det = 1/1

n=2: det=7/(12^2)

n=3  det = 647/(2160^2)

n=4 det = (19 * 571)/(672000^2)

n=5 det = (179 * 179357)/(7*4233600000^2)

n=6 det = (97 * 157 * 384191938531)/(186313420339200000^2)

n=7 det = (23 * 1280587616051046200369)/(2067909047925770649600000^2)

n=8 det = (317 * 6337 * 25997 * 87403 * 511645991608091)/(365356847125734485878112256000000^2)

(and some more. Note that mysterious 7 which keeps popping up in the denominator, for n=5,9,11 )

n=9 det = (55091 * 7731550926975871647518813143593349)/(7 * 146968826339795671126721851844198400000000^2)

n=10 det = (257 * 47360083 * 530916328215423816923887043836865928533)/(15402297982638230438765209613012092908994560000000000^2)

n=11 det = (31 * 1193 * 2647 * 538580971 * 957346850101 * 71222443011485886519799225151)/(7 * 175251348661711183890804992735665222783492739007774720000000000^2))

Comment: These seem to be related to the numerators and denominators of *permanents* of the Hilbert matrices: http://oeis.org/A101812 http://oeis.org/A101811 http://oeis.org/A092326

Comment: Cool! There may be a theorem lurking here...

Comment: Indeed there is. See (3.9) of http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004

Comment: Very cool! Still doesn't explain the humongous prime factors, though :(

Comment: Is there some reason you didnt factor the denominator for the $n=4$ case into its squareful and squarefree parts like the others? Note that its squarefree part also contains 7 (along with 3 and 5)...

Comment: @ARupinski: Typo: 672000 IS the square root, will fix.

Answer (score 13):

The determinant formula for $\det (1/(x_i+y_j)^2)_{i,j}$ is due to Borchardt, see Krattenthaler's article given in Steve's answer, which contains a $(q)$-deformation of it as well. I want to mention, that Emmanuel Preissmann conjectured also a formula for the generalized Cauchy determinant identity 
$$\det \left(\frac{1}{(x_i+y_j)^k}\right)_{i,j}$$  for *every* $k\ge 1$, see http://ipg.epfl.ch/~leveque/Conjectures/cauchy.pdf. 
Further generalizations of Cauchy's determinant identity are given in Okada's paper 
http://www.math.kobe-u.ac.jp/publications/rlm18/9.pdf, where $(1.6)$ is again Borchardt's identity.

Answer (score 11):

See (3.9) and (3.10)/Theorem 25 in Krattenthaler's "Advanced determinant calculus",  http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004

Comment: Alas, a cursory web search reveals nothing about the permanent of Hilbert matrices...

Comment: It is given in Theorem $25$, for $q=1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: the paper states that "equation (3.9) results immediately from (3.10) by setting $q = 1$." Am I missing an explicit formula for the permanent?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that the comparison of $(3.9)$ and $(3.10),q=1$ yields a formula for the permanent of the matrix $(1/(x_i-y_j)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had hoped that the specific instance of the Hilbert matrix might have a simpler form.

Answer (score 10):

Just a couple observations, building upon and explaining why Igor Rivin found that the denominators are often perfect squares or close to being such.

Let $A$ be the matrix with components $A_{ij} = 1/(x_i + y_j)^2$.  Expressing its determinant as a sum over permutations and putting everything on the same denominator gives
$$
\det A = \frac{P(\{x_i\}, \{y_i\})}{\prod_{i,j} (x_i + y_j)^2} \,,
$$
for some polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients.  Also, if two $x_i$ or two $y_i$ are equal, then the corresponding rows/columns are equal, and the determinant vanishes.  Hence
$$
\det A = \frac{Q(\{x_i\}, \{y_i\}) \prod_{i\neq j} (x_i - x_j) (y_i - y_j)}{\prod_{i,j} (x_i + y_j)^2} \,.
$$
Actually, as pointed out in other answers, the Cauchy formula provides $Q$ as the permanent of some matrix, but all I need here is to know $Q$ has integer coefficients.

In your particular case, the products give
$$
\frac{\prod_{i\neq j} (i - j) ((i - 1) - (j - 1))}{\prod_{i,j} (i + j - 1)^2}
=
\frac{\prod_{i < j} (j - i)^4}{\prod_{i,j} (i + j - 1)^2}
=
\prod_{j=1}^N \left[(j - 1)!^4 \frac{(j - 1)!^2}{(j + N - 1)!^2} \right]
=
\frac{\prod_{j=0}^{N-1} j!^8}{\prod_{j=0}^{2N-1} j!^2}
$$
Note that $j!^8$ divides $(2j)!(2j+1)!$, so the numerator divides the denominator.  All in all,
$$
\det A = \frac{Q}{\prod_{j=0}^{2N-1} j!^2 \bigg/ \prod_{j=0}^{N-1} j!^8}
$$
for some integer $Q$.  The denominator appearing in this formula is typically rather close to the ones given in Igor Rivin's answer, and are trivially squares: $1$, $12^2$, $2160^2$, $6048000^2 = 672000^2 \cdot 9^2$, etc.  The discrepancy is of course accounted for by cancellations between $Q$ and the product of factorials.  Again using Igor Rivin's data, I find (indices denote the size of the matrix)
$$
\begin{aligned}
  Q_1 &= 1 \\
  Q_2 &= 7 \\
  Q_3 &= 647 = 2^3 \cdot 3^4 - 1 = 8 \cdot (16 \cdot (6 - 1) + 1) - 1 \\
  Q_4 &= 878769 = 16 \cdot (12 \cdot (32 \cdot (144 - 1) + 1) - 1) + 1 \\
  Q_5 &= 18203480001 = 40000 \cdot ( 48 \cdot ( 120 \cdot (80 - 1) + 1) - 1) + 1 \\
  Q_6 &= 5850859031888599 \,.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here I've included some expressions which may or may not generalize.  In any case, it is certain that $Q$ will not be expressed as a (simple) product, as it involves some very large prime factors.