# What is known about the spectrum of a Cauchy matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

Math people:

A Cauchy matrix is an $m$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ whose elements have the form 
$a_{i,j} = \frac{1}{x_i-y_j}$, with $x_i \neq y_j$ for all $(i, j)$, and the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s belong to a field (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix).  Also it seems to be part of the definition that the $x_i$'s and $y_j$'s are all distinct (does anyone know why?).  I am only interested in the case where the field is the real numbers, and all the $x_i$'s and $y_j$'s are positive integers.  My question is, what is known about the eigenvalues of a square, real Cauchy matrix?  There is a formula for its determinant, which gives you their product, and the trace of the matrix, which is their sum, is easy to find.  I have Googled this extensively and found almost nothing.

I originally posted this on Math Stack Exchange but I got no answers so I removed the question and I am posting it here.

Comment: If $x_i=x_j$ or $y_i=y_j$ for some $i\neq j$, then the Cauchy determinant would be zero, and the matrix singular.

Comment: @DietrichBurde : I realize that.  Why would it be so terrible if the matrix were singular?

Comment: It would not be terrible. You can define singular Cauchy matrices, if you want. For solving Cauchy systems of equations invertible matrices are preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x_i > 0$ and $y_j -x_j$, then $c_{ij} = 1/(x_i+x_j)$. These matrices are infinitely divisible, i.e., $[c_{ij}^r]$ is also positive definite for all $r > 0$.

Spectral properties of Cauchy-like matrices and kernels are studied [here.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.81.3678&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
For additional information and an easier read, on the general case ($1/(x_i+y_j)$), you might enjoy looking at the [recent book by Pinkus](http://books.google.com/books?id=H8fwqfqACdEC&lpg=PA92&ots=dNykJhjse4&dq=totally%20positive%20cauchy%20matrix&pg=PA92#v=onepage&q=totally%20positive%20cauchy%20matrix&f=false).

Comment: Thanks.  In your first sentence, do you mean $y_j - x_j > 0$ for all $j$?

Comment: in the case $x_i > 0$ and $c_{ij} = 1/(x_i+x_j)$, are any bounds known on the (positive) eigenvalues of the matrix?

Comment: @Stefan: Have a look at my older answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/a/137093/8430 --- that bound (suitably modified to your case) will yield a lower bound on the eigenvalues; more refined analysis is also possible for upper bounds I think.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases the Cauchy matrix can be shown to be positive definite, see:

Horn, Roger A.
The Hadamard product. Matrix theory and applications (Phoenix, AZ, 1989), 87–169, 
Proc. Sympos. Appl. Math., 40, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1990. 
15-02 (15A42 15A45 15A69)